# What does "Page" signify in rails activescaffold action links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionlink, activescaffold

In the below line, what does page signify?

```
config.action_links.add 'export_csv', :label => 'Export to Excel', :page => true
```

What will happen if I make it false?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[When `true`, the link will open with standard HTML behavior.](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/API:-Action-Link#page)

Comment: I don't know what "standard HTML behavior" means.